# How to set divs in table cell using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to set multiple divs in table cell with class col-md-6 using bootstrap

Comment: why do u need to do it.??

Comment: Can u tell me exactly what u want to do in brief ?

Comment: I want to text message and button together. it is working on fine when original device but when i change device width lost button align and text alignment

Comment: I'm not getting it properly , Can u Post Your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@if(array_key_exists($record['keyword'],$eval_data)){{$eval_data[$record['keyword']]}}   Re-Evaluate@else
                                                            Evaluate@endif